# If $ad<bc$, there exist $k,n$ such that $ abd^2 k^2 < n^2 < b^2cd k^2 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I'm working on a long excersice, and I'm stuck in one particular step...

Given some fixed integers $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ad<bc$, which value $k\in\mathbb{N}$ should I take to ensure the existence of an integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that verifies the following?

$$ abd^2 k^2 < n^2 < b^2cd k^2$$

In other words, I want to construct a $k$ dependant at most of $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that the above interval sandwich any perfect square.
I verify it computationally with several examples, and it seems to work. Even more, the existence of such $n$  makes sense because these two facts:

First, you can see that the  factor $(bdk)^2$ behaves like an homotethic transformation over the interval $(ad,bc)$, and therefore you can strech it as much as you want choosing large values of $k$.

On the other hand, the frequency in which perfect squares occur is quite often, because that sequence is just the sum of consecutive odd integers:
$ n^2= \sum_{j=1}^n (2j-1)$

Any ideas please?

---

**Edit #1**: I want to thank all the users who answered and commented. You gave me a deeper insight of this problem, but unfortunately I have omitted an important detail that makes me unable to use the solutions proposed so far. The thing is, this problem is the only incomplete step I left in my own version of proving the existence of the real numbers. Therefor, I can't make any reference to its properties, or to square roots. This is the reason I stated everything in terms of integers. I need the construction to stay within rational numbers at most.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading.  If we take $a=2,b=1,c=1,d=3$ then we have $ab<cd$, yes?  But $abd^2=18$ and $cdb^2=3$ so your desired inequalities are not possible in this case.

Comment: You are right. Let me check if I have a typo of my notes or this is a grotesque error....

Comment: @lulu The condition is $ad\lt bc$ and this is multiplied by $bdk^2$ to get values which are supposed to sandwich $n^2$.

Comment: @MarkBennet  Oh, of course.  Thank you.

Comment: I note that the question header still reads $ab<cd$

Comment: @lulu  I think I corrected all the mixed $d$'s and $b$'s in the title and the text.

Comment: I agree. Not seeing a good approach (which doesn't mean there isn't one).

Comment: Hint: you're seeking any rational in the interval $(\sqrt{ab}d, b\sqrt{cd})$. If $a,b,c,d$ includes negatives, the interval to consider will change.

Comment: @Macavity Yes, I've noticed that if I find any interval with rational extremes contained in the one you mentioned, I can solve this. My problem was that I'm not good enough with inequalities. When I tried to upper bound $\sqrt{ab} d$ the only way I found have no guarantee that doesn't go beyond $b \sqrt{cd}$, and similarly with the other side of the interval..

Comment: Isn't it enough to take any $k$ such that $k^{-1} < \sqrt{bd}(\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad})$? Then there exists $n$ such that $\sqrt{bd}\sqrt{ad} < n/k < \sqrt{bd}\sqrt{bc}$, i.e. $abd^2 < n^2/k^2 < b^2cd$, as required.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yes, indeed. But is there a way to make such $k$ explicit?

Comment: Wait, now I'm not sure if that work... If you start with $k^{-1} < \sqrt{bd} (\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad} ) $, you will need to set $n=kd\sqrt{ab}   +1$ and if you take $k$ an integer $n$ could be not, depending on $a$ and $b$ which are fixed in the first place... Or did I miss something?

Comment: I'll double-check after dinner. Meanwhile, in response to your request for a more explicit solution: it would certainly be enough to take $k = 2c + 1$. This is overkill, but it ensures $k > 2\sqrt{c/d} \geqslant 2\sqrt{c/d}/(bc - ad) = 2\sqrt{c/d}/[(\sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ad})(\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad})] >2\sqrt{c/d}/[2\sqrt{bc}(\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad})] = 1/[\sqrt{bd}(\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad})]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding the comments I made earlier:

> If $x, y$ and $z$ are real numbers such that $0 < z < y - x$, then there exists an integer $n$ such that $$x < nz < y.$$

PROOF: If an integer $n$ is such that $nz \geqslant y$, then $(n - 1)z \geqslant y - z > x$. It follows that if $n$ is the least integer such that $nz > x$ - a unique such integer does exist, by standard properties of the reals and the integers - we cannot have $nz \geqslant y$. The conclusion follows. $\square$

We are given $ad < bc$, therefore $\sqrt{ad} < \sqrt{bc}$, therefore $\sqrt{bd}\cdot\sqrt{ad} < \sqrt{bd}\cdot\sqrt{bc}$.

Let $k$ be any integer such that $$\frac{1}{k} < \sqrt{bd}\cdot(\sqrt{bc} - \sqrt{ad}).$$

Again, such an integer does exist, by standard properties of the reals and the integers.

By the proposition highlighted above, there exists an integer $n$ such that

$$\sqrt{bd}\cdot\sqrt{ad} < \frac{n}{k} < \sqrt{bd}\cdot\sqrt{bc}.$$

This condition simplifies to $abd^2k^2 < n^2 < b^2cdk^2$, as required.

To get a 'simple' value of $k$ that suffices, rewrite its defining condition as

$$k > \frac{\sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ad}}{\sqrt{bd}\cdot(bc - ad)}.$$

Because $ad < bc$, and $a, b, c, d$ are integers, we have $bc - ad \geqslant 1$, so a sufficient condition for $k$ is

$$k > \frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bd}} = 2\sqrt{\frac{c}{d}}.$$

We must assume $d \geqslant 1$ (or the problem has no solution), so it suffices to take $k > 2\sqrt{c}$. But $ad < bc$, therefore $c \geqslant 1$, therefore $c \geqslant \sqrt{c}$. So we may take $k$ to be any value greater than $2c$, such as $2c + 1$.

**Edit:**

The strict inequalities involving $k$ at the end could actually be replaced by non-strict ones: $k \geqslant 2\sqrt{c/d}$, $k \geqslant 2\sqrt{c}$, $k \geqslant 2c$.

---

Here is a proof using only the properties of the natural numbers.

(The small use made of rational arithmetic can probably be easily avoided.)

Let positive integers $m, r$ be such that there is no positive integer $n$ satisfying the inequalities $$r(m - 1) < n^2 < rm.$$ Then there exists a positive integer $q$ such that $$(q - 1)^2 \leqslant r(m - 1) < rm \leqslant q^2.$$
Consequently, $r \leqslant 2q - 1$, and
$$\frac{m - 1}{m} \geqslant \frac{(q - 1)^2}{q^2}.$$
We can rewrite the latter inequality as $$m \geqslant \frac{q^2}{2q - 1},$$
which then gives $$4m \geqslant 2q + 1 +  \frac{1}{2q - 1} > r + 2.$$
This proves:

> If positive integers $m, r$ satisfy the inequality $r \geqslant 4m - 2$, then there exists a positive integer $n$ satisfying the inequalities: $$r(m - 1) < n^2 < rm.$$

In this result, take $m = bc$, and $r = 4bc^2d = 4cdm \geqslant 4m$.
The conclusion is that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that
$$4bc^2d(bc - 1) < n^2 < 4b^2c^3d.$$
Write $k = 2c$. Then we have:
$$abd^2k^2 = 4abc^2d^2 = 4bc^2d(ad) \leqslant
4bc^2d(bc - 1) < n^2 < 4b^2c^3d = b^2cdk^2,$$
as required.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your last edition. The fist part works impeccable, and I was still struggling with the existence of the $n$. I'm a little bussy right now but let me think about your argument and tomorrow I'll tell you if you solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Карпатський My apologies, too. I did wonder if perhaps the system hadn't automatically notified you of the edit - as it would have done in the case of a new answer, or even a comment. I had debated with myself whether an edit of the existing answer or else a separate answer would be more appropriate. I decided on the former, to avoid seeming too greedy for reputation points, but now I see that there is at least one argument in the other direction, too!

Answer (score 2):

When we subtract the square root of two integer and we get $\leq 1$ this tells us that at most, these integers are consecutive squares, so to ensure that there is a square between $a d b d k^2$ and $b c b d k^2$ and since the latter is bigger because $a d < b c$ we need to make sure that $\sqrt{b c b d k^2} - \sqrt{a d b d k^2} >1$ which is just $(\sqrt{b^2 c d } k - \sqrt{a b d^2 }k)  >1$  which is just $(\sqrt{c d} b - \sqrt{a b}d )k >1$ divide by $\sqrt{c d} b - \sqrt{a b}d >0$ which we know its true then we get that $k > \frac{1}{b\sqrt{c d}  - d\sqrt{a b} }$

For example : $a=5,b=4,c=9,d=7$ we get from the inequality that $k > \frac{1}{b\sqrt{c d}  - d\sqrt{a b} }= \frac{1}{4\sqrt{9*7}-7\sqrt{5*4}} \approx 2.252$

Because $k$ is integer then $k \geq 3$, will give infinitely many solutions for these fixed $a,b,c,d$.

For explicit formula, then how about $ k = \lceil \frac{1}{b\sqrt{c d}  - d\sqrt{a b} } \rceil+1$, adding one because the inequality have the notion $>$ and not $\geq$.

Generalized explicit formula is $ k = \lceil \frac{1}{b\sqrt{c d}  - d\sqrt{a b} } \rceil+m$ such that $m \in \mathbb{N} \geq 1$.